# Python convert string to list (No .split())

Tags: python, django, string, list

I've got a little problem:

I have a String in my Database which is called `actions`.
Now, I'm writing a method, which gets that string from the database 
(that works), and then I want to turn that string into a list.

I know `actions.split()`, but this didn't work out so well for me, because if my string looks like this:

```
actions = [
    {u'action': 'visit_testing', u'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 12, 13, 32, 14)},
    {u'action': 'visit_foo', u'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 12, 13, 37, 50)}
]
```

I can't use `actions.split(', ')` because it would mess up the dictionaries inside.

Till now I've got the following code:

```
timestamp = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
dict = {'timestamp': timestamp, 'action': action}

if self.actions:
    actions_string = str(self.actions)
    actions_stripped = actions_string.strip('[')
    actions_stripped = actions_stripped.strip(']')
    actions_splitted = actions_stripped.split(', ')

    new_action_list = []

    buffer = ''
     for string in actions_splitted:
        if '{' in string:
            buffer = str(string)
        elif '}' in string:
            buffer = buffer + ', ' + str(string)
            new_action_list.append(str(buffer))
            buffer = ''
        else:
            buffer = buffer + ', ' + str(string)
    self.actions = str(buffer)
    self.last_action = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
    self.save()
else:
    self.actions = '['+str(dict)+']'
    self.last_action = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
    self.save()
```

Addition: If I run the method when `actions` is empty, it gives me a list with one dictionary, but if I run it when it already has something in it, if sets actions to `""`.

Comment: "I have a String in my Database", you have json forced in as a string in your database, it probably needs to be a `JSONField`or an actual object model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to store valid JSON in your database. You *can* create a valid `action` list from that string using `exec`. But please beware that using `exec` or `eval` is a potentially [dangerous practice](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

```
import datetime

stuff = '''
actions = [{u'action': 'visit_testing', u'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 12, 13, 32, 14)}, {u'action': 'visit_foo', u'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 12, 13, 37, 50)}]
'''

exec(stuff)
print(actions)
print(actions[0]['timestamp'])
```

**output**

```
[{u'action': 'visit_testing', u'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 12, 13, 32, 14)}, {u'action': 'visit_foo', u'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 12, 13, 37, 50)}]
2016-02-12 13:32:14
```

Answer (score 1):

Use json library.

```
import json
my_dict_or_list = json.loads(your_string)
```

then work with Python objects. You will gain so much time :-D

Comment: now i'm getting Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

Comment: json keys in dict are enclosed with double quotes, not simple quote. Can you have your string with these quotes ?

Comment: I tried to change this line dict = {"timestamp": timestamp, "action": action}, but the quotes were changed back into single quotes... can i do .replace("'", '"')?

Comment: It should works but beware of string with escaped quote is your dict (i don't know if you can have some)

Comment: Json works only with double quotes. replace those single quotes with replace() method as you were telling

Comment: The problem is you're doing it too early, you later call `str` on the dict which just reverses the issue, you can see this in a console by doing `str({"test":"x"})`, I still think the model is the real problem..

Comment: So, now i changed dict = str({"timestamp": timestamp, "action": action}) and added new_dict = dict.replace("'", '"') now I got actions = [{u"action": "visit_testing", u"timestamp": datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 12, 13, 57, 32)}] inside my database. The problem is, If i run the method again, I'm getting ValueError at /t/none/
Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

Comment: @Sayse where is a JSONField in django models?

Comment: Why use json.loads() on something that's not json?

Answer (score -2):

I found a way that works for me:

```
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)

    if self.actions:
        new_dict = {"timestamp": timestamp, "action": action}
        #tmp_actions = json.loads(self.actions)
        tmp_actions = self.actions
        exec(tmp_actions)
        actions.append(new_dict)
        self.actions = str('actions = '+str(actions))
        self.last_action = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
        self.save()
    else:
        exec('''actions = ['''+str({"timestamp": timestamp, "action": action})+''']''')
        self.actions = 'actions = '+str(actions)
        self.last_action = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
        self.save()
```

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: This code will get you into trouble one day or another. Image what will happens if someone stores something like "os.system("rm -rf")" in your database...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yea, i know, but I guess I could write a method which checks if the text is "valid" (looks if a specific format is there)

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, I wouldn't bet my system security on this. Seriously, you'd better switch to (at least) json and write a run-once migration script for your current dat.  Or use a properly normalized relational schema storing "actions" in their own table, one row per action.

Comment: Well, I guess I'm going to create its own table then